# File name cannot be empty ftp_get

Tags: php

Downloading  multiple files from ftp and files are present on server, My code works and prints the filename from ftp but cant download the file.

```
$login_result = ftp_login($con, $server['stager_usr'], $server['stager_pwd']);
ftp_pasv($con, true);

$now = time();
$yesterday = $now - (24 * 60 * 60);
$date = date("Y-m-d", $yesterday);
if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
    $date = $_GET['date'];
}

$date_dir = strftime("/%Y-%m-%d", $yesterday);
$date_dir = $server['basedir'].$date_dir;

$path =  $server['basedir'];

$serverDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$imagesTop = "/CSV";


$startDate = "$date 00:00:00";
$endDate = "$date 23:59:59";

$files = ftp_nlist($con,$date_dir);
$date_dir =  strftime("%Y-%m-%d", $yesterday);
$date_dir = $path . $date_dir;
  foreach ($files as  $file)
 {
        if (preg_match("/\.csv$/i", $file))
        {
            echo"\n  Found $file \n";
              ftp_get($con, $serverDir, $file, FTP_BINARY);
           }

      }
}



 ftp_close($con);
}
}

//}
?
```

PHP Warning:  ftp_get(): Filename cannot be empty in /usr/local/bin/camftp.php o                                                                                                                                                                             n line 126
PHP Warning:  ftp_get(): Error opening  in /usr/local/bin/camftp.php on line 126

Comment: $date_dir is the path of the remote file  which is been fetched from ftp_nlist, and $serverDir is where I want download the files to.

Comment: Apologies, I misread your code. I deleted my comment to avoid confusion

Comment: Is your script running from command line or via a webserver? `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not defined if you launch your script via command line

Comment: command line , As I declared  serverDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] any suggestons where it should be declared on the code.

Comment: My question is: are you running your script from command line? If so, you can't use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` at all. You need to use for example `__DIR__` to get the path to the local file

Comment: Can you please let me know how to use this If my local path is : /var/www/CSV/